# Why didn't Sasuke put Naruto or his Kurama in genjutsu during Naruto vs Sasuke?

Tags: naruto

It only makes sense, he could have won easily that way if Obito can put a Jinchuriki (Yagura) under a Genjutsu, then why can't Sasuke? His eyes clearly surpass Obito's.

Why didn't Sasuke put Naruto or his Kurama in genjutsu during their battle?

Comment: Sasuke WANTED to fight Naruto. Putting Naruto under a Genjutsu wasn't going to make Naruto fight.

Comment: from what I saw, he only wanted to sever the bond between him and Naruto by killing him, he could have done that by putting him under a genjutsu very easily..

Comment: but I guess genjutsu from Indra reincarnated doesn't work on Ashura reincarnates so maybe thats the reason and maybe Sasuke knew that, or Yagura could be put under a genjutsu as he wasn't friends with 3 tails and only stole his chakra like Naruto first did to Kurama..

Comment: if there is another Chakra inside a person that will automatically disturb genjutsu. Naruto & Kurama already works together. and Obito use Kotoamatsukami on both Yagura & 3 tails.

Comment: where did you get the idea of Obito using Kotoamatsukami  ?

Comment: Yagura had tamed Isobu when he got trapped in the Genjutsu.

Answer (score 2):

To break out of a genjutsu you can disrupt your chakra flow. Although Sasuke's genjutsu is very strong, Naruto and the kyuubi are fully compatible, so the kyuubi can easily break Naruto out of a genjutsu if Sasuke tries to subjugate him.

Comment: If anyone needs evidence as to why this is the case, Look at Sasuke vs Killer Bee. Sasuke basically died if not for Jugo because he thought his Genjutsu would work against Bee and Gyuki

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe Sasuke subconsciously needed to be convinced to cooperate with Naruto.

Perhaps again, it is possible Genjutsu does not work on Sages. But hey, Sasuke put the tailed beasts almost instantaneously under Genjutsu and pressed on with Shibaku Tensei. The tailed beasts should have Sage chakra since they are partitions (in the mathematical sense of the word) of the Juubi.

Kurama noted that the Juubi is almost entirely made of energy like the one Naruto started wielding during his training with Fukusaku at Myobokuzan, the reason why he stood in the way of Fukusaku trying to merge with Naruto since he didn't want Naruto to resort to such power while he was in Naruto.

Comment: i don't think tailed beast chakra is sage mode chakra as Naruto's moves in Kurama Chakra Mode didn't effect Obito when he was the ten tail's jinchuuriki..he had to use sage mode to attack Obito..

Comment: My last sentence says exactly what you are saying. "since he didn't want naruto to resort to such power while he was in naruto" (of Kyubi). If Kyubi opposed Naruto's resorting to a "sort" of power as per his own terms, then clearly that "sort" of power is power "different" from what he Kurama had to offer.

Comment: oh, I thought you said that tailed beasts had sage chakra like the ten tails too..

Answer (score 1):

Naruto is a Perfect Jinchuraki, so genjutsu won't work on him,  which  was shown when Sasuke was fighting Killer Bee and even if  he wasn't Sasuke can't decipher between the real Naruto and SC.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto is a Perfect Jinchuraki, so genjutsu won't work on him, which was shown when Sasuke was fighting Killer Bee he couldn't use genjutsu cause he also was a perfect jinchuriki. To break out of a genjutsu you can disrupt your chakra flow. Although Sasuke's genjutsu is very strong, Naruto and the Kurama are fully compatible, so the Kurama can easily break Naruto out of a genjutsu if Sasuke tries to subjugate him.
Look, now you can say that how Obito did genjutsu on Yagura...The answer is, he was not a friend with he 3 tails so, the 3 tails didn't help him by giving him his chakra to break the genjutsu...And, also this could happen that as Hagoromo gave both Naruto and Sasuke six paths it is easy for Naruto to break genjutsu with the power of Kurama and Sage mode it is easier and Kurama is also there to break Naruto's genjutsu by using Kurama's chakra, and Naruto already knows that Sharingan's power and how he can avoid it and it is, even more, easier to avoid it with the speed of his...He could also use sage mode to get Nature chakra which also modifies his chakra
Knowing all these, Sasuke didn't try to waste his time and take a risk as he did while with killer bee & were about to die...And, he was also well aware of Naruto's power so he just went to the furthest step he could to finish Naruto as soon as possible...

Answer (score -2):

Because Kishimoto wanted the anime to be 500 episodes long.

Casting genjutsu and killing him just as Cee did it in Raikage vs Sasuke fight, it would have taken at most 10 mins including filler. So not an option for an anime which has half of filler episodes, it would imbalance the ratio :)

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. It'd be great if you could provide references that Kishimoto did this intentionally to backup your answer. Otherwise, pure speculation or personal theory without any base don't really add any value.